Local (Browser) Notifications in iOS Safari standalone mode
Do Local Notifications work at all in iOS Safari or standalone apps? I don't mean Push Notifications with service workers, but the ones initiated from the browser with new Notification().
There isn't any result from new Notification().
Permissions are granted; the context is secure; the app is added to the Home Screen; "Notifications" flag in Safari Advanced WebKit settings is turned on.
